# using data from script file in handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm working on node.js/express app and I'm using handlebars as a template engine. I know how to send data to hbs template using res.render('results',{data}) but in this case this is not possible. I'm trying to display some data generated in script.js on handlebar template page but I can't make it.

I have tried to include

```
<script id="selected-analysis" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 {{#if visibility}}
  {{city}}
 {{/if}}
</script>

<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
```

on results.hbs page and code bellow on script.js page

```
let theTemplateScript = document.getElementById("selected-analysis").innerHTML;
let theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
let display = {
  "visibility":true,
  "city":'beo'
}

let theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(display)
document.querySelector('.content-placeholder').innerHTML += theCompiledHtml
```

On main.hbs I have

```
<script src="/dist/handlebars-v4.4.3.js"charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In my app.js file I have set handlebars middleware

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
 defaultLayout:'main',
 helpers:helpers,
 extname:'.hbs'
}))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
```

could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try using **app.set('view engine', '.hbs');** in app.js.

Please modify app.js as below

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
defaultLayout:'main',
 helpers:helpers,
 extname:'.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but this actually is not related to the question I have asked